# guard-rspec not doing anything when specs or models are saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, guard

I installed `guard` 2.2.5, and `guard-rspec` 4.2.0. I ran `guard init rspec`, opened a new terminal window, and launched `guard`.

I get the following output:

```
01:16:08 - INFO - Guard is using Tmux to send notifications.
01:16:08 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
01:16:08 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
01:16:08 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/myapp'
[1] guard(main)>
```

When I save any models, specs, etc, nothing happens.  I thought guard was supposed to run automatically? If I press enter on the guard prompt, it runs all specs, but that's all I can seem to get it to do.  What am I doing wrong?

My guardfile as follows:

```
guard :rspec do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml|\.slim)$})          { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml|slim)$})     { |m| "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
end
```

Comment: You might need to delete the content of the Guardfile and write it by hand, instead of using the defaults, add a line at a time and restart guard then change a file and watch if guard would take effects or not, do that in bits, then what OS are you running on.... Guard behavior varies a bit across OSes

Comment: Even if I reduce the guardfile to just `guard :rspec do watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$}) end` still NOTHING happens when I save any of my `_spec.rb` files, or models themselves.

Comment: Does https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Add-Readline-support-to-Ruby-on-Mac-OS-X apply to you?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin how would I know? It's unclear why anyone would land on that wiki page in the first place, and I hesitate to reinstall Ruby just to test this?

Comment: As an aside, guard works fine in a brand new rails app on the same version of ruby, so I assume it is related to something in my project in particular.